# Regex to require numbers, then a space, then letters?

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible in regex (using javascript if that matters) to require numbers, then a space, then letters?

I'm not even sure where to begin..

I know this works if I was doing it in an HTML5 pattern...

```
pattern="[0-9]+[ ][a-zA-Z0-9]+"
```

But that's an HTML5 pattern, and I'm trying to figure out the regex equivalent.

Comment: A HTML5 pattern **is** a RegEx

Comment: That's correct. I would do this `\d+\s\w+` but your way is fine as well. Of course note with both `[a-zA-Z0-9]` and `\w` you are including numbers.

Comment: To turn that into JavaScript, just use `/[0-9]+[ ][a-zA-Z0-9]+/`. The Regex syntax is exactly the same.

Comment: Ah, learn something new every day!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work for you. It's exactly what you're trying to do just more concise.

```
/\d+\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+/gi
```

`\d+` matches any **digit** *one or more times*
`\s`   matches any **whitespace**
`[a-zA-Z0-9]+` matches any **letters or numbers** *one or more times*.

This is what your current RegEx is showing but if you want to truly only have letters like you specify:

> Is it possible in regex (using javascript if that matters) to require numbers, then a space, **then letters**?

Use: `/\d+\s[a-z]+/gi`

---

The `g` and `i` modifiers state that the pattern should search **globally** and case **insensitively**

**Example**: https://regex101.com/r/8tmFY9/3

More info on [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: Note that this will match strings like `5 _`. `\w` matches letters, numbers, *and underscores*, while `\s` matches any white space character. To match **exactly** what OP describes, it should be something along the lines of `/\d+[ ][a-z]+/i`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. Really appreciate you also explaining why it works. Why give a man regex when you can teach a man to regex. =